# Accessing union's member variable: declared for uint64, but want something in uint32. c++

Tags: c++, unions

Say I want to assign some random value, and the only option for the random value is returned in uint32_t. I want to assign that value to some union variable in uint64_t. So I do the following, which doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>       /* time */

class A{
public:
    A(){
        srand (time(NULL));
        A_ = rand(); // Also error
        // What i want ::
        // A_.A32 = rand();
    }

    union A_{
        uint64_t A64_;
        struct  A32{
            uint32_t a32_1;
            uint32_t a32_2;
        };
    };
};

int main(){
    A a;
}
```

How can I possibly solve this problem of unable to use something in uint32_t, such as assigining some uint32_t value to a32_1 or a32_2?

Error message is as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -        MF"src/myNeo.d" -MT"src/myNeo.d" -o "src/myNeo.o" "../src/myNeo.cpp"
../src/myNeo.cpp:57:6: error: expected unqualified-id
```

Comment: Union aliasing is not supported in Standard C++, I would recommend you take an entirely different approach

Comment: @M.M I can get it to work on my llvm compiler with anonymous union, but g++ complains with error saying this is not supported in Standard C++. So I guess with actually not-anonymous unions, it's just impossible?

Comment: Here are several ways to do what it seems like you want: https://ideone.com/isWCFA I don't know why you want it. and it certainly seems like a bad idea, but it shows you syntax.

Comment: @RetiredNinja wow... thank you

Comment: It sounds like an XY problem. You can use [<random>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) functions to directly generate uint64_t random values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `A_` defines a type, not a variable. You need a variable to write into, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h> /* time */

class A {
public:
    A() {
        srand (time(NULL));
        u.U32_1 = rand();
        u.U32_2 = ...;
    }

    union U {
        uint64_t U64;
        struct {
            uint32_t U32_1;
            uint32_t U32_2;
        };
    };

    U u;
};

int main() {
    A a;
}
```

On the other hand, if your goal is just to get a 32bit integer into a 64bit integer, you can assign it as-is and let the compiler extend the value for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h> /* time */

class A {
public:
    A() {
        srand (time(NULL));
        u = rand();
    }

uint64_t u;
};
```